# Calulate the eigenvalues and the eigenstates

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-mechanics

> An observable is given by $$\sum\limits_{n= 1}^N a_n|a_n\rangle\langle a_n | $$ Here $\langle a_n |a_m\rangle = \delta_{nm}$. What are the possible measurement results corresponding to the operator A and what are the possible states of the system after measurement?

How do I calculate the eigenvalues and states when only the operator is given? If I proceed with the answer as follows:
 $$A \vert a_n \rangle = \sum\limits_{n= 1}^N a_n |a_n\rangle \langle a_n|a_n\rangle = \sum\limits_{n= 1}^N a_n |a_n\rangle= a_n \vert a_n \rangle  $$ Can I say that $a_n$ is the eigenvalue and $|a_n\rangle$ the eigenstate?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is observable (operator), we have:
$$A \vert a_m \rangle = \sum\limits_{n= 1}^N a_n |a_n\rangle \langle a_n|a_m\rangle = \sum\limits_{n= 1}^N a_n |a_n\rangle \delta_{mn} = a_m \vert a_m \rangle  $$

then yes, $a_n$ is eigenvalue and $|a_n\rangle$ is its corresponding eigenstate (eigenvector).

Also, elements of A can be found as:

$$
A_{nm} = \langle a_n|A|a_m\rangle = \langle a_n|(a_m \vert a_m \rangle)= a_m \delta_{mn} 
$$